# Frequency Spectrum of a composite signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, spectrum

I have added two signals of frequencies .2 and .45 Hz and obtained a new signal.The fundamental frequency on my calculation is 1/20 Hz.But the spectrum shows different one.Am I wrong somewhere?

```
t2=0:1/360:10-(1/360);
s1=.33*cos(2*pi*.2*t2);
s2=.22*cos(2*pi*.45*t2);
baseline=s1+s2;
Fs = 360;                      % samples per secon               % seconds
N = size(t,2);
%% Frequency specifications:
dF = Fs/N;                      % hertz
f = -Fs/2:dF:Fs/2-dF;
x_axis=f;
% figure(3)
f_response=(abs(fftshift((fft(baseline-mean(baseline))))));
figure(1)
plot(t2,baseline); %BASELINE WANDER
xlabel('time');
ylabel('amplitude');
figure(2)
plot(t,fr);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in line 6: `N = size(t2,2);`

Comment: I have just tried it, I corrected also the variables names in line 12 and 18. The result is correct. You have to keep in mind the circularity of the FFT, now is some time I am not playing with FFT, try to review how to recover the right frequency. **The result of the FFT is ever between 0 and 1** you have to scale it on your frequency.

N.B.
The two spikes you see in the result are the two sins.